# How to search among all the commands / functions?

Tags: search

I often forget the names of many commands and always have to look up the internet or the manual but it would be good if i could search within emacs among all the commands / functions

For eg: I know there is a commands to export org file to html but do not know how it begins...so would be great if i could just search for 'export' in all available commands and get a list of all functions which have export in their name.

how can i do this?

I am still amateur so pardon for asking very simple question..

Comment: The easiest thing to do is start `C-h f` and try to complete function names, e.g. by typing `org*html` followed by one or more `TAB`s. The more general solution is to use an apropos command. See [`(emacs) Apropos`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Apropos.html). Yet another solution is to use a completion framework which supports fuzzy or out-of-order completion, such as [`ivy`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/), [`helm`](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/) or [`icicles`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).

Comment: @Basil: Please consider posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command `apropos-command` (**`C-h a`**) to see summary info about available commands.

Use command `apropos-function` to see summary info about available functions (including commands).

These commands let you type a regular expression or some keywords, and they find command/function names that match what you typed.

See the Emacs manual, node [Apropos](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Apropos.html), for more information.